# Is there a sefer on yeridas hadoros?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

I'm looking for a sefer (ideally Hebrew, from a distinguished Rabbi) on the concept of yeridas hadoros. I have no clue if one even exists, but I figured I'd ask on the forum and see what people have to suggest. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm inclined to say that no such sefer exists because no-one is worthy to write it; but then who am I to comment?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok It may have been written by a Rabbi from a previous generation

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok very clever, got a good chuckle outta that!

Answer (score 1):

Not in Hebrew, not by a distinguished rabbi, and arguably not a *sefer*:

[*Maimonides on the “Decline of the Generations” and the Nature of Rabbinic Authority*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/949981.Maimonides_on_the_decline_of_the_Generations_and_the_Nature_of_Rabbinic_Authority) by [Menachem Kellner](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Kellner).

Comment: Also על כתפי ענקים by Avraham Melamed  (same caveats, except the 1st)

Answer (score 1):

Look at igeres sherira gaon. He discusses the idea of yeridas hadoros especially in light of mesiras hatorah. i.e. What changed which caused the style of mesiras hatorah to change.
It's written in Aramaic and I saw an edition which had Hebrew translation.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full sefer, but it's worth highlighting the [Chida's comments on Eruvin 21b](https://www.sefaria.org/Petach_Einayim_on_Eruvin.21b.3?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he):

> שמא תאמר אם יש בהן ממש מפני [מה] לא נכתבו א"ק עשות ספרים הרבה אין קץ ולהג הרבה יגיעת בשר. אפשר לפרש דהא דכתיב ולהג הרבה חוץ מדרשא דבסמו' הוא טעם שני למה לא נכתבו דעל ידי שהם בע"פ וצריכי רבנן למגריסינהו תדיר ולא פסיק זה גורם להתקדש ולהשתעבד שעבודא דאורייתא כי חיים הם למוצאיהם ומרחקתו מן החטא וז"ש ולהג הרבה שהוגה בהן עי"ז יגיעת בשר על דרך שאמרו שיגיעת שניהם משכחת עון וזה טעם גדול לתורה שבע"פ. והוא טוב טעם לקדושת התנאים והאמוראים מלבד תוקף עילוי נשמתם שעל ידי שהיו מוכרחים תדיר לחזור על לימודם בעל פה היה מזדכך גופם ותורה אגוני מגנא ואצולי מצלא לא כן אחר שנכתבה הגמרא דבטלה הגירסא בהתמדה ושרו חכימי' למהוי כעמא דארעא וזה מפתח גדול להבין האי דאחסור דרי וסדר הבדלות בין חכמי ישראל ודי בזה:

In brief, he says that the verse the Gemara cites there ([Koheles 12:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.12.12?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) may be hinting at a second reason why Torah Shebaal Peh was originally unwritten (besides the one given in the Gemara there, that the sheer mass of material would be impractical to write down): the effort needed to memorize Torah Shebaal Peh itself made people holier. Once Torah Shebaal Peh was written down (with the closing of the Talmud) and it was no longer necessary to memorize it, there was a yeridas hadoros, and "the sages began to become like the amei haaretz."

In his closing words he notes that "this is an important key to understanding the descent of the generations and the distinctions between Torah sages," but doesn't elaborate. (He may mean that the transitions from the Tannaim to the Amoraim, and from the Rishonim to the Acharonim, are similarly associated with codifications of the basics of Torah Shebaal Peh, such that less effort was needed to memorize the basics. He might also be alluding to the invention of printing at the close of the era of the Rishonim, which put many more sefarim within reach of Torah scholars and sages, but at the same time reduced the amount of effort needed to learn those sefarim. One wonders, in that case, what he'd make of the explosion of Torah knowledge available on the Internet!)